# XML deserialization: Deserialize missing element into null property value

Tags: .net, xml, deserialization

My xml document has a  element that can contains multiple  child elements. In my class, I declare the property as:

```
[XmlArray("files", IsNullable = true)]
[XmlArrayItem("file", IsNullable = false)]
public List<File> Files { get; set; }
```

During deserialization, if the `<files>` element is missing, I want the Files property to be **null**. However, what happens is that Files is deserialized into an empty List object. How do I prevent that?

Comment: I meant, if the <files> element is missing, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that achieves that is encapsulation of the list:

```
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("files", IsNullable = true)]
    public FooFiles Files { get; set; }

}
public class FooFiles
{
    [XmlElement("file", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Here, `Foo.Files` will be `null` if there is no `<files/>` element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way which can avoid creating additional class.

Comment: @superkinhluan - not as far as I know; as you can see, the list is created eagerly