# XML Deserialization of a List in an optional Element

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have two possible xmls to deserialize.

Without the `<UrmDevices>` node:

```
<Account Id="1514478">
   <UrmDevice Id="66e24068-4ef4-4f7e-a675-a67bb8497611" FriendlyName="Device1" RegisteredTime="2018-03-13T07:54:03Z" LastUsed="2018-03-13T07:54:03Z" DeviceType=""/>
   <UrmDevice Id="9ead24cf-978c-4bbf-bd87-4e5d08c9c0d0" FriendlyName="Device2" RegisteredTime="2018-03-13T07:54:02Z" LastUsed="2018-03-13T07:54:02Z" DeviceType=""/>
</Account>
```

With the `<UrmDevices>` node:

```
<Account Id="1514478">
   <UrmDevices>
      <UrmDevice Id="66e24068-4ef4-4f7e-a675-a67bb8497611" FriendlyName="Device1" RegisteredTime="2018-03-13T07:54:03Z" LastUsed="2018-03-13T07:54:03Z" DeviceType=""/>
      <UrmDevice Id="9ead24cf-978c-4bbf-bd87-4e5d08c9c0d0" FriendlyName="Device2" RegisteredTime="2018-03-13T07:54:02Z" LastUsed="2018-03-13T07:54:02Z" DeviceType=""/>
   </UrmDevices>
</Account>
```

Class currently looks like this:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot("Account")]
public class Account
{
    [XmlArray("UrmDevices", IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlArrayItem("UrmDevice")]
    public List<UrmDevice> UrmDevices { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the `<UrmDevices>` to be ignored so the object would be Account.UrmDevices regardless of the `<UrmDevices>` existance.

So far I have tried IsNullable attributes (as shown in the code above), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927452/xml-deserialization-deserialize-missing-element-into-null-property-value), which is not actually a solution... Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really nasty hack might be:

```
[XmlRoot("Account")]
public class Account
{
    [XmlArray("UrmDevices", IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlArrayItem("UrmDevice")]
    public List<UrmDevice> UrmDevices { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("UrmDevice")] // shadow UrmDevices with different layout
    public List<UrmDevice> EvilUrmDevices {
        get { return UrmDevices; }
        set { UrmDevices = value; }
    }

    // disable serialize of one of the two
    public bool ShouldSerializeEvilUrmDevices() { return false; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

completely untested, and... shudder.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Marc! Your "evil shadowing" solution does indeed work. Would you by any chance think of a single-property solution? (without the EvilUrmDevices reflected in the Accounts object)

Comment: @Kalnius if I could think of one, I would have posted it

Comment: Makes sense. Silly [desperate] question.